# How to send Transactions errors from the model to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, transactions

I have a standard Rails transaction in a Token model that transfers credits to a User upon success. Is there an easy way to transmit a transaction failed error back up to the control if / when that happens? Here is the Token model code:

```
def self.verify(token, user)
  token.user_id     = user.id
  token.redeemed    = true
  user.credits      += token.credits
  begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    token.save!
    user.save!
  end
  rescue => e
    puts 'Token transaction failed!'
    token.errors.add(:base, 'Token transaction failuress!!')
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you better explain what are you trying to achieve with controller code?

Comment: This is Model code. I want to bubble this transaction error up to display it in a flash from the Token controller... off this token instance maybe?

Comment: You can re throw this error with raise(e) in rescue block and catch it again in controller. Or just return this error as return value of verify method